# Lambda function not inserting into Postgres RDS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, lambda, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I am trying to insert a record into RDS Postgres using node.js lambda function.  I can't tell if it is connecting to the database or not.  It did insert 3 records once and then nothing.  Nothing is being written to the log.  Below is my code:

```
'use strict';

 const { Client } = require('pg') ; 
 const client = new Client();
 client.connect();
  

exports.handler = async function(event, context) {
  
 var response;
  
  if (event.Records) {    
    for (let record of event.Records) {
    
        var rec = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(record.body));
        var test = JSON.parse(rec);

        console.log("test id:" + test.id);
        
        const queryString = {
            text: "INSERT INTO public.order VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)",
            values: [test.id, test.email, test.total_price, test.token],
        };
  
        try{
            const result = await client.query(queryString);       
            console.log(result.rowCount);        
            response = result.rowCount;
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err.stack);
        } 
}
    client.end();
}
  return response;
};
```

The log output is:

INFO    test id:820982911946154500

INFO    Error: Client was closed and is not queryable    at /opt/nodejs/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:570:27    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: are you sure `event.Records` evaluates to true?

Comment: @Daniel Farrell - Yes it does evaluate to true. It is processing a record from SQS.  I am trying to process a message/record from SQS and insert it into DB.  So test.id has the right value.  The issue is inserting it into db.

Comment: interesting that your console log message doesn't show in the log output

Comment: Yes because the log I copied above was from when I was invoked the lambda function from the console.  It is in fact displaying the right id when I test the whole sequence i.e from my data source to API Gateway -> SQS - > Lambda function.  Copying the log from SQS:

Comment: The log from SQS does show an error  - my bad! - 
INFO 
test id:820982911946154500

INFO Error: Client was closed and is not queryable    at /opt/nodejs/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:570:27    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this after changing to pg.Pool() to manage the connections based on this post - [Node.js - PostgreSQL (pg) : Client has already been connected. You cannot reuse a client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63074649/node-js-postgresql-pg-client-has-already-been-connected-you-cannot-reuse)